# I am trying to solve the hacker rank problem. I am still a beginner and I don't know where I went wrong with Python 3

Tags: python

THIS IS THE QUESTION:
Given an array of integers, find and print the maximum number of integers you can select from the array such that the absolute difference between any two of the chosen integers is less than or equal to 1

```
def pickingNumbers(a):
    maxi=0
    for i in a:
        x=a.count(i)
        y=a.count(i-1)
        x=x+y
        if x>maxi :
            maxi=x
    print(maxi)     
if __name__ == '__main__':
    fptr = open(os.environ['OUTPUT_PATH'], 'w')

    n = int(input().strip())
    a = list(map(int, input().rstrip().split()))

    result = pickingNumbers(a)

    fptr.write(str(result) + '\n')

    fptr.close()
```

given input:

```
6
4 6 5 3 3 1
```

expected output: `3`

my output: `None`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You printed the value of maxi at the end of `pickingNumbers` instead of returning it.

As you don't explicitely return a value, your function returns `None`, which get converted to the string `'None'` in `str(result)`

Just replace it:

```
def pickingNumbers(a):
    maxi = 0
    for i in a:
        x = a.count(i)
        y = a.count(i-1)
        x = x+y
        if x > maxi :
            maxi = x
    return maxi
```

and you should be fine...

Comment: OH Right!.I did not pay attention.Thank You So Much:)